# ORDER BY 0 errors out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query which I am trying to understand as to what it is doing

the query is:

```
SELECT orderid, 
       shippeddate 
FROM   Sales.Orders 
ORDER  BY ( CASE 
              WHEN [shippeddate] IS NULL THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
            END ), 
          [shippeddate]
```

I understand theat when the nulls are present in the shippeddate column, it will order by orderid
but I don't understand the Else case, what does Order bY 0 do, because when I tried to use it without the Case statement as in the follwing query, it errors out:

```
        SELECT orderid, shippeddate
        FROM Sales.Orders
        ORDER BY 0
```

Any help on as to what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: SQL counts from 1, not 0.  In the version with expressions, you aren't using the ordinal column numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that when the nulls are present in the shippeddate column, it will order by orderid

This is *not* what happens. The purpose here is to make sure that all of the records that have a value for `shippeddate` are shown before those that don't have value.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is ordering by 2 columns, firstly a calculated value based on `shippeddate` being `null` or a `date` and secondly by the actual `shippeddate`:

```
CASE WHEN [shippeddate] IS NULL THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
END
```

The first part of the `ORDER BY` is effectively creating a new calculated column per row that is simply storing `NULL` date values as `1` and valid dates as `0`.

So with this data:

```
id  | shippeddate
----|------------
 1  | null
 2  | null
 3  | 2015-01-21
 4  | 2015-01-18
```

The case statement would produce the following set of values:

```
id  | shippeddate | order_col (hidden)
----|-------------|-------------------
 1  | null        | 1
 2  | null        | 1
 3  | 2015-01-21  | 0
 4  | 2015-01-18  | 0
```

So if you order by this calculated value in the hidden column, the `0` values will come before the `1` values. So valid dates would come before `NULL` values.

The second `ORDER BY` value `[shippeddate]` simply orders the dates, so the output would be:

```
id  | shippeddate | order_col (hidden)
----|-------------|-------------------
 4  | 2015-01-18  | 0
 3  | 2015-01-21  | 0
 1  | null        | 1
 2  | null        | 1
```

Comment: And there you have it. Thanks Tanner. Explained very well. Vote++

Comment: Agreed, because some of these answers are simply not true, and I think they should be deleted to be honest. The only 2 people that knew what they are saying were you and Joel. Well done again

Answer (score 0):

Order by 1 means ORDER by Column1.

when you try to do ORDER BY 1 it takes first column

In the same way when you try to execute ORDER BY 0 it results an error because of no column no.0 .
As there is no Zeroth column.

Try to use this.

```
 SELECT orderid, shippeddate
     FROM Sales.Orders
     ORDER BY 
             (
            CASE 
            WHEN [shippeddate] IS NULL THEN 1
            ELSE
            [shippeddate]
            END
             )
```

Comment: but then how does it work within the case statement .. that's what i am trying to understand. here is is being used to sort the nulls last using case statement.

Comment: @Priya Read Joel's answer. This does not answer your question. Look at Tanners answer for a very good explanation

Comment: this answer is misleading as it explains why the (second) select query doesn't work but doesn't answer the question. the original (first) query works, but the OP doesn't understand the CASE section, so there is no need to provide an alternate query for the first query posted.